# iPhone : Simple UITableViewController crash without console error nor debugging clue

Tags: iphone, debugging, uitableview, console, crash

I'm trying to build a simple TableView program struture.
It seems to work fine, but if I scroll the list to high or to low, the app crashes without any console error and the trace into the debugger does not help.

You can see it by yourself looking at the project I put at : http://shine.free.fr/tmp/myTestApp.zip

Can you help me :

- to know what goes wrong
- to know how I may find what goes wrong without having to ask each time. Usually I check my connection, lokk for compile errors, look into the console and try to debug, but there, nothing helps me.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your ListController object is not retained when it is loaded from nib file, so it is not guaranteed that it will be valid after nib is loaded (and in fact it is not). To solve your problem add an outlet for ListController property and define retaining property for it. Here's `FenetreListeController.h` that fixes your problem:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ListeController;

@interface FenetreListeController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet ListeController* listController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ListeController* listController;
@end
```

You will also need to set outlet connection in IB and synthesize property in .m file

For more information about how objects are loaded from xib files check ["The Nib Object Life Cycle"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18) section from "Resource Programming Guide"

Comment: While searching for a solution after my post, I tried to compile both xib into just one, without changing anything in the code. And this works fine !  Uhh ? The source code of this second try is at http://shine.free.fr/tmp/myTestApp2.zip (just a little addition to test the button. The code is kept the same and the nibs are compiled). Could you tell me why the app crashes in the first method, and not in the second one ? And perhaps most important of all, how would I find the cause of that problem without any console error or debug trace ?

Comment: Any idea about my last comment ?

Comment: It seems (although I had not much time to look) the 2nd one works because you have retain property for your FenetreController in application delegate, so it does not get deallocated prematurely. It is hard to tell how to trace this kinds of errors, except that such weird crashes are most likely be caused by memory problems so it is the directino you should look...